# How can I blacklist filetypes from Spotlight search results?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Spotlight has a quirk that I want to fix, if possible. When I search for certain keywords, such as categories in System Preferences, Spotlight will place a document as the "Top Hit" in the search results, even though System Preferences have a higher priority over Documents in Spotlight's preferences. I want to be able to blacklist certain filetypes while preserving the "Documents" category.

For example, typing "sharing" will return the top hit as "sharing.qml" from the Qt5.1.1 directory, followed by Sharing in System Preferences. I can't then immediately press enter to open "Sharing" without first pressing the down arrow.

[image: Sharing with incorrect ordering of results]

---

What I am able to do to fix this individual issue is blacklist the Qt5.1.1 `examples` directory.

[image: Second incorrect result]

You can see that it returns "sharing.html" from the gtk-doc directory now. So I blacklist that directory as well.

[image: Finally]

Now I am able to search for "Sharing" with no issues. However, there are other search results that exhibit similar behavior, such as when typing "mouse". It is too tedious to block each directory that I find.

[image: I don't want a rkt file]

---

[image: Settings for Spotlight]

---

I want to be able to blacklist **individual filetypes** from Spotlight. I have set "System Preferences" to have a higher priority than "Documents" in Spotlight as well. Nothing seems to affect the "Top Hit" other than individually blacklisting each directory that holds a file that I don't want to see.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the importer used to import that type of file.

   ```
   mdimport -d 4 -n /path/to/file 2>&1 | grep Imported
   ```

   ```
   mdimport -d 4 -n ~/Desktop/avatar.png 2>&1 | grep Imported
   2014-06-19 11:17:04.929 mdimport[30911:412893] Imported '/Users/grgarside/Desktop/avatar.png' of type 'public.png' with plugIn /System/Library/Spotlight/Image.mdimporter.
   ```

   <sup>The above example shows the type as *public.png* in the *Image.mdimporter* importer.</sup>
2. Open `/path/to/importer/Contents/Info.plist` in an editor.
3. Find the item of the same type as the type of the file that you found from the above command and delete it.

   [image]
4. Reimport the importer.

   ```
   mdimport -r /path/to/importer
   ```

   ```
   mdimport -r /System/Library/Spotlight/Image.mdimporter
   ```

Don't forget to have backups and note this procedure may be overridden on OS X updates.

Comment: This looks like it *should* work. However, the command with `grep Imported` does not output anything for either the path for `sharing.qml` or `mouse.rkt`.

Comment: @aglasser What do you get if you run the command without the pipe? Just try running this: `mdimport -d 4 -n /path/to/file 2>&1`

Comment: Ah, I am foolish. I should have tried that before. It was because there are spaces in the path to each file... Escaping them works now. Thanks for your insight. I will try the entire process and get back to you if it works or not! `2014-06-19 12:31:00.382 mdimport[18293:507] Imported '/Applications/Racket v5.3.6/collects/frtime/demos/mouse.rkt' of type 'org.racket-lang.source' with plugIn /System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter.`